# Blazemeter Plugin cannot be installed in Google Chrome Error Displayed: "UTILITY_PROCESS_CRASHED_WHILE_TRYING_TO_INSTALL" in Ubuntu 12.04 OS

Tags: automated-testing, tools, test-automation-framework, browser-automation, browsers

Trying to install Blazemeter Plugin in Google chrome, but i am not able to. It is giving an error as below:  "UTILITY_PROCESS_CRASHED_WHILE_TRYING_TO_INSTALL" in Ubuntu 12.04 OS.

How should i proceeed?

Comment: Did you try to contact the blazemeter support forum for this?

Comment: Yes milin i have emailed to support

Comment: What did they say?

Comment: Yet no reply from support

Comment: Okay. Well give it a day or 2. I  the meanwhile can you give more details to reproduce the issue, like browser version, blazemeter version and screenshot of the issue, etc

Comment: In which OS are you running the Chrome browser? Mac? Windows? Ubuntu?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Alon as mentioned it is Ubuntu 12.04 and it's compatible version

Comment: I'm from BlazeMeter. I see a ticket was created for the issue. I apologize no-one ever got back to you. I'll make sure it's taken care of and replied to here.

Comment: Thank you Ophir for you fine observation, awaiting for resolution.

Comment: Hi milin, may i please know how to get server stats like cpu usage etc and the generate load report from blaze meter is our the stats of client computer or server. If it's of client how i will be able to get server stats.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Chrome bug that affects all extensions (not only BlazeMeter extension) with multiple versions of Ubuntu. 
I see its been confirmed as bug in Chrome issue queue and has been assigned. Hopefully will be fixed soon.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=401655

Some people reported that updating your Kernel to 3.16 or 3.17 fixes the issue.